# Include not working on ef-core2.0

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Working on a aspnetcore2.0 project in VS2017

The '.Include(o => o.OrderEventLogs)'  clause is not working in the following query:

```
       var orders = _repository.GetDbSet<Order>()
             .Where(o => o.RiskCellId == int.Parse(riskCellId) && 
                    o.OrderDate.ToShortDateString() == OrderDate.ToShortDateString())
             .Include(o => o.OrderEventLogs)
             .Include(o => o.Instrument) 
             .ToList();
```

Is not loading the related OrderEventLog entities. (Actually sometimes it does work, sometimes it doesn't. Same query, same parameters)

It's really weird because this related entities are included when I run this query:

```
        var order = _repository.GetDbSet<Order>()
            .Where(o => o.Id == Guid.Parse(orderId))
            .Include(o => o.OrderEventLogs)
            .Include(o => o.Instrument)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Both pieces of code run just fine in previous ef-core versions

Packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

UPDATE

It seems to work fine if I do this:

```
       var orders = _repository.GetDbSet<Order>()
             .Where(o => o.RiskCellId == int.Parse(riskCellId) && 
                    o.OrderDate.ToShortDateString() == OrderDate.ToShortDateString())
             .Include(o => o.Instrument) 
             .ToList();

        foreach (Order order in orders)
        {
            _repository.Context.Entry(order).Collection(e => e.OrderEventLogs)
                .Load();
        }
```

Comment: I see no question here. Consider posting the case to EFC issue tracker. I'll put my bet on client evaluation of `ToShortDateString()`, so if you are looking for workaround, try eliminating it, for instance with `o.OrderDate.Date == OrderDate.Date`

Comment: I guess this hasn't been fixed yet, I'm facing the same issue. .Context.Entry(order).Collection(e => e.OrderEventLogs)
                .Load() works